# Selected Attribute in select doesn't work

Tags: html

```html
<select class="form-control" selected="CM"><option value="BAG">BAG</option><option value="BX">Box</option><option value="CM">Centimeters</option><option value="CRD">Card</option><option value="KG">Kilo grams</option></select>
```

how to make CM selected as default? i usually use this way but it seems not working now

Comment: Please research first, there are many same question like yours already answered.

Comment: do you think i didnt do the research?

Comment: Well it's very easy, just type how to make option selected in select html. Try it, many answer will pop-up

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `selected` property to the `<option>` element.

```html
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="BAG">BAG</option>
  <option value="BX">Box</option>
  <option value="CM" selected>Centimeters</option>
  <option value="CRD">Card</option>
  <option value="KG">Kilo grams</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i kow this way, but in may case this select will be built from a javascript, then i want to set selected option depends on what we defined before dynamically

Comment: Therefore your question should be `how do I select an option in a select with javascript?`
Please change your question and include additional details, so to get a more accurate answer  :)